# Leaving sick from work

Tags: management, united-states

I am a leasing/office asst. agent and my boss was gone from the office for 2 weeks. During the second week after being by myself, I began to feel my blood pressure rising/166/100.  I called the dr. and he wanted to see me.  I called my boss and she told me that the office had to remain open.  I called the boss over her to get permission over her, since there was no guarantee that I was able to come back.  There was only 3 hours left for the office to close.  The dr. had me off work for the following 3 days.  My boss was angry and told me to send the dr's note and write a letter stating that I couldn't perform my duties, all to be sent to HR.  Of course I refused! So now coming back to work on Monday.  She basically took all responsibilities from me as her assistant and is paying me only half commission on the Move Ins that I did because the files weren't set up.  I told her I wasn't going to argue with her.  So I let be.  Is this against the labor law?

Comment: "of course I refused" please elaborate. Many offices have a policy of wanting a doctor's note after more than a day or two off sick. Why would you not only refuse, but label it with "of course"?

Comment: Also, which country is this?  Laws vary substantially from country to country.

Comment: I supplied the dr.'s note but not the letter of me being unable to do my job.  I live in the state of Florida.

Comment: So if I get it right, your boss asked you to submit a letter and "of course" you refused, and now you are wondering if it is against the law?

Comment: She wants *you* to write a letter? That should be easy. A single signed statement saying exactly that should be enough.

Comment: All the critical information should be in the note provided by the doctor.

Comment: Did you notify your boss "Hi boss, the doctor asked me to take the next 3 days off."

Comment: This question is very hard to read, partially due to all of the personal details that are unnecessary for answering your question. You could rephrase it to "I was feeling sick during working hours so I went to a doctor to get checked out against my superior's orders. The doctor advised me to stay at home for 3 days. I did/didn't communicate this to my employer at the time. Now that I'm back, all of my responsibilities have been taken away and I'm only receiving half pay. Is this legal? I live and work in the US state of Florida. "

Comment: The answer to your question is "ask a lawyer".

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of the law, in your situation I would definitely supply all the information asked for by your employer in order to demonstrate good faith.

Your employer has no real way to know if you just wanted to close the office early for a beer or if your telling the truth.  In this case, your doctor should have no problem supplying the required paperwork for you *making it easy for both you and your employer*.  Specifically, the Doctor should state the recommendation of you not being able to work.

Best bet in these scenarios is to be as cooperative as you can and provide the required documentation -- especially in your case where its easy to do so.

Comment: Like stated prior, I did submit the dr.'s note for the three days.  My question basically is of her asking me to write a letter indicating that due to my health I couldn't perform my duties.  Now those are words out of her mouth not mine.  I get the feeling she was or is trying to find a way to have me fired.  Mind you a barely miss work. Also, if it is legal for her not to pay half of my earned commission just because the files weren't set up..this being because I left early that day and she had to do it for me when she came back and I was still out.

Comment: @Milly Read my entire answer.  You stated the doctor said you should not or could not work, did your letter from the doctor state that?

Comment: @milly actually you said "of course I refused" to send the doctors note and write the letter.